# How do I just look at a specific row with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Python Pandas. So sorry for a very easy question. But I'm trying to target all restaurants that are on the street Commonwealth.

Wouldn't this be the way to target it:

```
commonwealth = df[df['Street'] == 'Commonwealth AV']

 Restaurant Number Street
    a          700    Commonwealth AV
    b          300    Faneuil Hall ST
    c          440    Commonwealth AV
```

However, I am not getting any returns?

In addition, right before I targeted 'Street,' I actually separated the address into 'Street' and 'Number.' I am not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: What do you mean you're not getting any returns? What are the contents of df, and what are the contents of commonwealth after you execute that line?

Comment: The contents of df include "Restaurant", "Number", "Street", "City", "Address", "Violstatus", etc. When I execute commonwealth, I get a len count of 0

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong with the code you've pasted here. Without knowing what's in the dataframe (meaning what all of the elements in it are), it's not possible to debug

Comment: check for trailing spaces in the values.

Comment: What you posted looks fine. And like @PaulH said, check whitespaces. There might be a space before the street names.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a small, self-contained example with sample data demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It had to do with a space before the street names. Thank you

Comment: @dancemc15 if it is whitespaces try this and see if it works: `commonwealth = df[df['Street'].str.strip() == 'Commonealth AV']` check out the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, you've got some white space in your string. The clue to this is that that street names are showing up offset from the column name. Try

```
df['Street'] = df['Street'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

to clear out all of the whitespace. Then

```
df[df['Street'] == 'Commonwealth AV']
```

or

```
df.loc[df['Street'] == 'Commonwealth AV', :]
```

should get you the slices where the street is `Commonwealth AV`